# Is it possible to create exs24 files with a script?

Tags: bash, script

Say that I have a hundred samples and want to make an exs24 instrument for each of them. Is there any script where I could input some info like name, key and path to the audio file and then have it generate an exs24 file for me?

If exs24 files were plain text, this would be easy to make myself. I tried making such a script myself but they are binary files.